# C++ metaprogramming recursive step limit

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, template-meta-programming

I'm giving template metaprogramming a go. Here is a simple example I came up with:

```
template <int n>
struct N
{
    static const int k = N<n-2>::k;
};

template<>
struct N<0>
{
    static const int k = 0;
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
}
```

The above works. Note that k is defined as `k = N<n-2>::k;`
The following fails:

```
template <int n>
struct N
{
    static const int k = N<n-3>::k;
};

template<>
struct N<0>
{
    static const int k = 0;
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
    cout << N<10>::k;
    getchar();
}
```

Same code, except now `k = N<n-3>:k;` The compiler complains about the code being too complex. This limit seems fairly arbitrary, is there a way to modify it?

Comment: What happens when you subtract `3` from `10` a few times? Do you reach `0`? Or do you perhaps go straight to `-1`?

Comment: Oh wow, just realised what the error was; you're right! Not sure what the SO procedure is, should i close this question?

Comment: It is up to you. I am too lazy to make my comment into an answer, but someone else might.

Comment: juanchopanza has the most important answer, but also: your first code snippet, intended to demonstrate the correctness of the `n-2` case, doesn't actually instantiate any templates anywhere, so it would still compile and run even if you changed `n-2` to `n-3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original recursion only terminates for even values of the template parameter n. You need two stop cases, for n == 0 and n == 1. In your revised example, you'd need 3 stop cases, or a stop case for n <= 0.